# How to set an extra to level field with python logstash logger,?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logstash

I'm currently using the python-logstash-async library, which is just a wrapper around python-logstash, essentially.

https://python-logstash-async.readthedocs.io

I've tried reading their docs in order to figure out how to set additional top level fields to the messages I'm sending.

At the moment I can only add additional fields to the `extra` object provided by the logger.

But the `extra` dictionary means all my extra fields are not at the top level.

Instead of sending:

```
{
 "message":"blah"
 "extra": {
  "blax":"baz"
 }
}
```

I want to send:

```
{
 "message":"blah"
  "blax":"baz"
}
```

Their docs quickly mention this as a possibility: https://python-logstash-async.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html?highlight=tags

But for the life of me I can't figure out how to actually add a customer configuration.

I need some some code examples for using a custom config or know of any other way to set a top level field in the message.

Answer (score 2):

I've just found a quick hack by adding the `extra` field into a constant variable:

```
from logstash_async.constants import constants
constants.FORMATTER_LOGSTASH_MESSAGE_FIELD_LIST.append('my_new_top_field')
logger.info('blah',extra={'my_new_top_field':'bar'})
```

Seem to result in the message

```
{
  'message':'blah',
  'my_new_top_field':'bar'
  ... etc
}
```

Being sent.

Which fixed my problem. However, I'll leave this open in case anyone comes up with the "proper" solution that uses the config object.

Answer (score 2):

From the linked docs: `extra_prefix: To disable grouping of the extra items and have them on the top level of the log event message, simply set this option to None or the empty string.`

The trick is to set `extra_prefix` to `None`, then all fields passed as `extra` to the log record are added at the top level of the Logstash event.

Example (untested):

```py
handler = AsynchronousLogstashHandler(...)
formatter = LogstashFormatter(extra_prefix=None)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
...
logger.info('blah',extra={'my_new_top_field':'bar'})
```